# How can I get detailed Easy Auth logs when using a Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-authentication

### The app

I have a web application on Microsoft Azure. The client is written in Vue.js and hosted via a Windows App Service. The server is built using Azure Functions, and hosted via a Linux Azure Functions App.

Both the client App Service and the server Function App use [built-in authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) ("Easy Auth"), with Active Directory configured as the identity provider. I am able to log into each, separately, via AD.

Until recently, I was also able to make authenticated requests from the client to the server. The client has

```js
"loginParameters": [
  "response_type=code id_token",
  "scope=openid offline_access api://<Application (client) ID>/user_impersonation"
]
```

in its `authsettingsV2` and generated tokens' `aud` have the correct application ID. Passing the `access_token` from the client's `/.auth/me` response as a bearer token in requests to the server used to work.

### The problem

I made a few configuration changes today, tested authentication, found that it was no longer working, and backed them out. Unfortunately, reverting those changes didn't fix the issue and generated tokens are no longer being accepted by Easy Auth on the server:

```json
{
  "code": 401,
  "message": "IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https:\/\/aka.ms\/IdentityModel\/PII.]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https:\/\/aka.ms\/IdentityModel\/PII.]' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https:\/\/aka.ms\/IdentityModel\/PII.]'."
}
```

Okay, so the issuer is not in the list of valid issuers. But [Azure hides personally identifiable information in exceptions by default](https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII) so I can't see the issuer or any of the valid issuers.

One option appears to be:

> If you need to see the full information present in exceptions, please set [IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.logging.identitymodeleventsource.showpii?view=azure-dotnet) to true

but this looks like a reference for configuring authentication myself using C#. I don't see any way to change this setting when using Easy Auth.

Maybe I can access raw logs. Let's see, [I should be able to see this information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#logging-and-tracing) by [enabling application logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer):

> If you enable application logging, you will see authentication and authorization traces directly in your log files

> To enable application logging for Linux apps or custom containers in the Azure portal, navigate to your app and select App Service logs.

But that option is not available:

[image: Screenshot from Azure Portal]

A lot of the Function App documentation links to App Service documentation, so it would seem that Function Apps are a special kind of App Service App, but maybe not. The preceding quote is from App Service documentation, but I got there following links from Azure Function App documentation.

Alright, let's see if there's a way to enable application logging for *Function* Apps. [Azure Monitor Logs look promising](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp), but none of the generated logs appear to be about Easy Auth. I just see messages about the service starting. Maybe that's because, on Linux apps, [Easy Auth runs in an isolated environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#feature-architecture-on-linux-and-containers) and therefore wouldn't be included in diagnostic logs:

> The authentication and authorization module runs in a separate container, isolated from your application code.

So… how can I get more details about this error? [Easy Auth is recommended as an option for authentication with Function Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts#enable-app-service-authenticationauthorization), and I'd hope that there's a way to get more information about what's happening.

---

I have seen [Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization returns HTTP 401 IDX10205: Issuer validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62220873/354577) and have already set `accessTokenAcceptedVersion` to `null` in the manifest. That Q&A helped me get the token passing working in the first place, and I have not changed that value.

Comment: I have found the cause of this error, but not via any helpful logs or debugging information from Azure. I would still like to know where such information can be found, if at all.

Comment: (FWIW, the cause was a subtle difference between two issuer strings. I'm pretty sure an unredacted version of the error message would have pointed me in the right direction much more directly than the path I ended up taking.)

Answer (score 1):

Although 'App Service Logs' are disabled on Azure Function on Consumption tier, there is still a method to obtain diagnostics information on [App Service Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRU5h.png) (AKA 'Easy Auth').

1. Navigate to the Azure Function in Azure Portal.
2. Open the 'Diagnose and solve problems' blade on the left menu.
3. In the search box, start typing 'Authentication' and then select from the search dropdown the 'Authentication Configuration and Investigation Detector (EasyAuth)' option.
   [image]

This opens a DaaS detector that shows the Easy Auth configuration, version, and error information (sample below):
[image]
[image]

Note that the information here is not in real time, and can take 15 minutes or more to update.

Comment: I dont see the particular token validation errors that I expected, do you know if there is some other setting that I'm missing? Like some log level stuff in `host.json`